# How can people drink 7-11 Slurpees and soda?

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

There is no real Hechser on 7-11 Slurpees. How do people drink them? Is going on the Star-K's list okay? What about soda from the machine? I found that 7-11 switches the spouts sometimes. So even if the soda is Kosher, what about other sodas that may have gone through those tubes?

Comment: "There is no real Hechser on 7-11 Slurpies". I am referring to NY

Comment: Please, a little respect - it's Slurpees, not Slurpies.

Comment: "There is no real hechsher on 7-11 Slurpees".  Excuse me?  Since when is the Star-K not a real hechsher?  (Little symbols on food packaging mean just as much as an approved list - either one is only as good as the agency behind it).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rabbi Sholem Fishbane has a comprehensive article about Slurpees here:
http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/slurpees.php

Regarding the nozzles of the machines, an article by Rabbi Dovid Cohen (http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/fountain_soda.php) describes how the CRC came to the conclusion that it does not pose a kashrus concern.

Answer (score 4):

The Star-K in this shiur discusses everything at length including what their list is all about, as well as all the issues:

[05/26/2010 Summer Delights – Slurpees, Sodas, Ice Cream, Ices (also follow-up on the fish worm issue discussed last month)](http://www.kosherclasses.org/mod/resource/view.php?id=177)

However, it appears you need to sign up to access the above link. A quick workaround: the shiur is also available [on iTunes Podcasts over here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/star-k-kosher-classes-podcast/id277285294) [it's the one dated 6/3/10].

And for reference: the [list of the Kosher slurpees](http://www.star-k.org/cons-appr-slurpee.htm) at Star-K.

Comment: I wonder ,Does this issue change from year to year?

Comment: @simchashatorah see my edit: there's a list which has a preface: " Since the kosher status of flavors can change at any time, the Star-K takes no responsibility. Consumers are urged to use their discretion with each individual 7-Eleven store."

Comment: @simchashatorah @yydl : The CRC updates their lists all the time. I don't know if there is any difference between their list and the Star-K list, but here it is: http://www.crcweb.org/slurpee_list.php (This list was updates 6/27/2011)